webcam frame rate drops on Asus laptop
We're experiencing webcam frame rate drops on an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 22.04 in our home grown recording application. When we use qv4l2 to get a system view of the frame rate outside of our own application, we get displays like the following:

The effective frame rate shown at the bottom of that qv4l2 window gets arbitrarily lower than the specified one. This happens both for the built-in laptop's webcam, and for external USB connected ones which normally operate with the same laptop at 30 fps at the shown resolution, as intended, and which are known to work at that rate for that resolution.
Some times the frame rate is as expected, and during other times it gets halved and worse, as exemplified above. We're not using two webcams in parallel, so it wouldn't be USB bus contention, we just experience this oftenly, when using each one of the two webcams each in isolation. We're not aware that the laptop is running anything else that's causing load or bus contention either.
Other than switching the laptop to the "performance" power mode rather than the "balanced" or power saving ones, what should we be looking at in terms of system logs, give or take other utility programs, in order to figure out the possible reasons for the effective frame rates being arbitrarily lower than the frame rates being set?

Would you probe USB data transfer in any way?
Would you use any v4l2 commands to yield further helpful diagnostics?
Would you find system performance logs somewhere to rule out that the firmware is throttling CPU or data transfer to avoid heating?
Any guidance on what to look for in the gynormous output of sudo turbostat in these regards?


P.S. https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2024/09/real-time-linux-is-officially-part-of-the-kernel-after-decades-of-debate/
---
Edits Concerning the Expected USB Data Transfer Rates
Our code is acquiring MJPG at a 720x1280 frame size at 30 fps. Since (as far as I understand) MJPG means compressing each image on the camera side, we can expect this to be a data rate of 64.8 Mbps flowing on the bus from the camera on the USB bus, communication protocol overheads not included, if we arbitrarily assume an average compression rate of 1:10 per image.
Using the usbtop utility we actually see a rate of only 2.3 Mbps in practice, on machines where the rate issue does not manifest, which is a far cry from the 480 Mbps maximum speed of the USB 2.0 spec as much as I understand how advertized USB speeds translate to data rates.
We also see a negligible USB average rate of ~150Kbps from the computer to the camera at the same time, which is kind of negligible, though bringing to mind that some waits are obviously due by having to acknowledge the data from the receiving end.
We're not seeing any spike in CPU activity nor an easy to notice drop in cpu frequencies.

My first impression is the usage of inappropriate drivers. How old is that laptop? Please provide the model and variant.

Some details on the laptop could be useful.

The laptop is a ASUS Zenbook UX3402ZA. @StinaAndersson drivers? care to elaborate? We're following up on the diagnostics from below this month again following some logistics setbacks.

I tried and failed, it's a tricky one. Good luck!

Why failed? it was the most helpful suggested answer which sent us looking at the right things which anyone should look at with similar issues before really getting started! Care to undelete it for other people's sake? We're now focusing on the cpu frequency, which is managed by or through the driver (e.g. intel_pstate), cpu frequency governers, and to an extent autonomously by the hardware regardless of the former two.

We actually reproduce the issue also on Windows 11, on the same laptop, and also equally so with its internal webcam not just the logi. The camera shows as 30 fps, yet generated video using the default capturing app is 15 fps :\
